# Kafka Akka Streams Consumer interrupted with WakeupException after timeout. Message: null

Tags: scala, docker, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I am doing a simple code that:

1. Creates a kafka broker using docker
2. Publish messages using a scala akka producer
3. Consumes messages using a scala akka consumer.

The code and instructions how to run can be found in my github account:

https://github.com/dvirgiln/akka-streams-ts

The consumer it is failing:

```
  val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(system, new ByteArrayDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
.withBootstrapServers("192.168.99.100:9092")
.withGroupId("group1")
.withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")

  Consumer.plainSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("test")).mapAsync(1) { msg =>
val value = msg.value
logger.info(value)
Future(msg)}.runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

The exception I receive is:

```
[WARN] [04/29/2018 10:21:00.208] [default-akka.actor.default-         dispatcher-4] [akka://default/system/kafka-consumer-1] KafkaConsumer poll is taking significantly longer (10000ms) to return from poll then the configured poll interval (50ms). Waking up consumer to avoid thread starvation.
[WARN] [04/29/2018 10:21:00.216] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://default/system/kafka-consumer-1] Wake up has been triggered. Dumping stacks: Thread[default-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-7,5,main]
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:672)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:396)
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:238)
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:214)
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:190)
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:219)
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:205)
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:284)
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1146)
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1111)
akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor.tryPoll$1(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:298)
akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor.poll(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:345)
akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor.akka$kafka$KafkaConsumerActor$$receivePoll(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:267)
akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:170)
akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor.aroundReceive(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:85)
akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main]


Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]


Thread[default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4,5,main]
 java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method)
java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1607)
akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor.$anonfun$poll$1(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:283)
akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor$$Lambda$203/1530539777.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:140)
akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:43)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Thread[default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3,5,main]
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Thread[default-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6,5,main]
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thread[Monitor Ctrl-Break,5,main]
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2$1.run(AppMainV2.java:64)

Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

Thread[default-scheduler-1,5,main]
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.waitNanos(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:85)
akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:265)
akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

Thread[default-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-5,5,main]
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thread[default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2,5,main]
 akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Logging.scala:1015)
akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger.aroundReceive(Logging.scala:1012)
akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
[WARN] [04/29/2018 10:21:00.217] [default-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://default/system/kafka-consumer-1] Consumer interrupted with WakeupException after timeout. Message: null. Current value of akka.kafka.consumer.wakeup-timeout is 10000 milliseconds. Exception: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.maybeTriggerWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:442)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:251)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:214)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:190)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:219)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:284)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1146)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1111)
    at akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor.tryPoll$1(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:298)
    at akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor.poll(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:345)
    at akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor.akka$kafka$KafkaConsumerActor$$receivePoll(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:267)
    at akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:170)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor.aroundReceive(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:85)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```